# Sort array of NSDictionaries by a value inside one of the keys

Tags: ios, objective-c, sorting, nsarray, nsdictionary

I'm pulling an **XML** feed from a server, the feed contains train stations and their latitude and longitude locations.

I've managed to create an `NSArray` full of `NSDictionary` objects, each corresponding to a station.

In the dictionary there is a key for **latitude** and key for **longitude**. I also have a `CLLocation` object with the location of the device.

I know how to calculate the distance between the device and each station, but the distance isn't part of the dictionary. I would like to sort the array in order of distance from the device.

How would I do that? No idea where to start on this and Google or my books aren't being very helpful to me! Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: This post has the answer to your question: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/805547/how-to-sort-an-nsmutablearray-with-custom-objects-in-it][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/805547/how-to-sort-an-nsmutablearray-with-custom-objects-in-it

Comment: If anyone else is having a problem like this - make the array mutable, create a method using fast enumeration to add another field to each dictionary. Do the sort using blocks (as described in the link above)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use the following;

```
NSArray *sortedArray;
sortedArray = [unsortedArray sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(NSDictionary *first, NSDictionary *second) {
    // Calculate distances for each dictionary from the device
    // ...
    return [firstDistance compare:secondDistance];
}];
```

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, you can't sort `NSDictionary` objects. You should create `NSMutableArray` and sort it instead.

See this - [Collections Programming Topics - Sorting Arrays](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Collections/Articles/Arrays.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000132-SW5)

**Update:**
To sort array of dictionaries you can use for example this method of `NSArray`:

```
sortedArray = [someArray sortedArrayUsingFunction:compareElements context:NULL];
```

The `compareElements` function example:

```
NSInteger compareElements (id num1, id num2, void *context)
{
    int v1 = [[num1 objectForKey:@"distance"] integerValue];
    int v2 = [[num2 objectForKey:@"distance"] integerValue];
    if (v1 < v2)
        return NSOrderedAscending;
    else if (v1 > v2)
        return NSOrderedDescending;
    else
        return NSOrderedSame;
}
```

Comment: You can - he has an array of dictionaries.